# Postfix sending emails on port 25

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postfix, ubuntu-server, ubuntu-16.04

I've set up a postfix server and it seems to send emails on port 25 no matter what I do.

**/var/log/mail.log**

```
Aug  5 15:49:48 TheServer postfix/master[2225]: daemon started -- version 3.1.0, configuration /etc/postfix
Aug  5 15:49:48 TheServer postfix/qmgr[2227]: BA5881D20592: from=<user@mail.domain.us>, size=341, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug  5 15:49:50 TheServer postfix/qmgr[2227]: 8EF0B1D203E8: from=<user@mail.domain.us>, size=410, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug  5 15:49:50 TheServer postfix/qmgr[2227]: 4B8C71D205F8: from=<user@mail.domain.us>, size=355, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug  5 15:49:50 TheServer postfix/qmgr[2227]: 750711D2049B: from=<user@mail.domain.us>, size=410, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug  5 15:49:50 TheServer postfix/qmgr[2227]: DE9491D20598: from=<user@mail.domain.us>, size=363, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug  5 15:49:50 TheServer postfix/qmgr[2227]: C42411D20360: from=<user@mail.domain.us>, size=387, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug  5 15:49:50 TheServer postfix/smtp[2233]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400d:c00::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
```

The above has been edited to hide the domain name.

Postfix is added to my firewall, the ports are opened.

**/etc/postfix/master.cf**

```
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
#smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       y       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       y       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
```

Comment: What is your question? Postfix will send using port 25 is normal. Mail Transfer Agent (MTA) uses port 25 to communicate between one MTA to another [MTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent).

Comment: As Darius mentioned, [well-known port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports) 25 is the standard port used by mail servers to transmit email to other mail servers via [SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP), so why are you trying to change it to some other port?

Comment: You have to send mail on port 25, good luck sending it otherwise. Your problem is that you are probably doing this on a home network and port 25 is blocked. Most ISPs don't let home users run mail servers, it's a spam thing. You can try to get your ISP to open the port or you can relay through a smart host. That's it.

Comment: From what I understand you want to use submission port in order to send you mail via google or some other provider, i.e. use a smart relay host. If that is your goal, please restate your question to reflect that.